# How to specify date range in Google URL request?

Tags: python, parsing, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, urllib

I am trying to specify date range in Google News URL request, and whilst it works when I paste it into Chrome, urllib just retrieves all most recent articles, so I am not sure what the problem is.

I am trying to scrape the news articles about Coca Cola from 26/11/2018 to 26/12/2018. Instead, I receive most recent articles in the output. Here is the snippet of my code:

```
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen
from urllib.parse import quote
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import ssl
ssl._create_default_https_context = ssl._create_unverified_context

query = 'coca cola'
query_url = quote(query)
start_date = datetime.date(2018, 11, 26).strftime('%m/%d/%Y')
end_date = datetime.date(2018, 12, 26).strftime('%m/%d/%Y')

root = "https://www.google.com/"
link = f"https://www.google.com/search?start=0&q={query_url}&tbm=nws&tbs=cdr:1,cd_min:{start_date},cd_max:{end_date},sbd:1&lr=lang_en"


def news(link):
    req = Request(link, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
    webpage = urlopen(req).read()
    with requests.Session() as c:
        soup = BeautifulSoup(webpage, 'html.parser')
```

Comment: Add all of the import statements so its easier to run your code.

Comment: @Übermensch This is for a minimum reproducible example (so they don't have to include it), but I believe they are using a requests library and b4 soup. It's in their tags.

Comment: So, you don't need the modules (which are not all listed in the tags) in order to reproduce the problem?

Comment: @Übermensch It should be self-evident, but if you really need them, I already listed all if not most of them. The libraries are in the tags.

Answer (score 0):

### Update, it seems there is somthing in the Google side:

https://support.google.com/googlenews/thread/688982/how-can-i-search-news-articles-in-a-date-range?hl=en

---

Maybe I don't understand how this works, but the first thing I usually do when  trying to fix something, is comparing results with the real thing, and guess what:

[image]

So, two possibilities: I don't know how to use Google for searching using date ranges :D or those date ranges do not do what we think they do.

Comment: That's exactly my problem as well, I have been playing with that URL for so so long. I feel like Google is trying to introduce measures against scraping or I am just dumb lol

Comment: Nah, the date range for News just doesn't work. You code is Ok.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the wrong URL. You can use this fnc to create the correct URL:

```
def make_url(query, 
             m_min, 
             d_min, 
             y_min, 
             m_max, 
             d_max, 
             y_max):
    return f"https://www.google.com/search?q={query}&rlz=1C1CHBF_enUS1024US1025&biw=1564&bih=932&sxsrf=ALiCzsaGPneyPAo-kyllnxBBtXe-FGWorQ%3A1665448856808&source=lnt&tbs=sbd%3A1%2Ccdr%3A1%2Ccd_min%3A{m_min}%2F{d_min}%2F{y_min}%2Ccd_max%3A{m_max}%2F{d_max}%2F{y_max}&tbm=nws"
```

As for the scraping, I think you need to use `selenium` as I was not able to get all of the website's HTML with `requests`.

Here is what I tried using `requests` (which did not work):

```
import requests

def get_html(url, req_headers=None, req_cookies=None):
    # send GET request to url with requests
    response = requests.get(url, headers=req_headers, cookies=req_cookies)
    return response.content

if __name__ == "__main__":
    query = "coca+cola"
    m_min, d_min, y_min = 11, 26, 2018
    m_max, d_max, y_max = 12, 26, 2018

    url = make_url(query, m_min, d_min, y_min, m_max, d_max, y_max)

    my_headers = {
                 "Host": "www.google.com",
                 "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:109.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/110.0",
                 "Accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8",
                 "Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.5",
                 "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate, br",
                 "DNT": "1",
                 "Connection": "keep-alive",
                 "Upgrade-Insecure-Requests": "1",
                 "Sec-Fetch-Dest": "document",
                 "Sec-Fetch-Mode": "navigate",
                 "Sec-Fetch-Site": "none",
                 "Sec-Fetch-User": "?1",
                 "TE": "trailers"
    }

    my_cookies = {
                 "1P_JAR": "2023-03-17-05",
                 "AEC": "ARSKqsKiDrV7uWP3i_GOlRfeUWgjsp3a0H82KgZ2TYWrmyBGspwG69erZf0",
                 "ANID": "AHWqTUlS_ESog8QFpRLIUTdCKAYeUxq7ld3d7QlZ5SXns4Aj7u6fO-uq5Pdx-9ds",
                 "NID": "511=k1KAAxs-mhpWNgY4R9C7Q3X2Py2iGZuQxhko22Xxnv2ME9FEp2FiZJ3czYKb_xv4gOUqvX-MTr3FDuR9r5C3G4VkPj-PoI80gNJZCWFZHbI-8qR4fHG7lFO6vXl4WXuIjARJZvdKzqV9lxRE73re5RCE1l1Yk5lyJjCgDvBvDQ4"
    }

    print(get_html(url))
```

I was able to get the article links and dates with selenium:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from time import sleep

def make_url(query, 
             m_min, 
             d_min, 
             y_min, 
             m_max, 
             d_max, 
             y_max):
    return f"https://www.google.com/search?q={query}&rlz=1C1CHBF_enUS1024US1025&biw=1564&bih=932&sxsrf=ALiCzsaGPneyPAo-kyllnxBBtXe-FGWorQ%3A1665448856808&source=lnt&tbs=sbd%3A1%2Ccdr%3A1%2Ccd_min%3A{m_min}%2F{d_min}%2F{y_min}%2Ccd_max%3A{m_max}%2F{d_max}%2F{y_max}&tbm=nws"

# find all html elements with given css and get their text values
def parse_html_text(html, css_selector):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
    html_elements = soup.select(css_selector)
    text = [element.text for element in html_elements]
    return text


# Find all article links
def parse_html_urls(html, css_selector):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
    html_elements = soup.select(css_selector)
    href_values = [element.get('href') for element in html_elements]
    return href_values

# send GET request and execute website's JavaScript with Chromium driver
def get_and_render_html(url):
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    driver.get(url)

    # wait for all HTML to render
    sleep(3)

    page_source = driver.page_source

    # end selenium session
    driver.quit()
    return page_source

if __name__ == "__main__":

    # amek query string
    query = "coca+cola"

    # set date range
    m_min, d_min, y_min = 11, 26, 2018
    m_max, d_max, y_max = 12, 26, 2018

    url = make_url(query, m_min, d_min, y_min, m_max, d_max, y_max)
    pg_source = get_and_render_html(url)

    # use css selectors to parse html for desired information
    date_selector = "div.OSrXXb.ZE0LJd.YsWzw"
    publish_dates = parse_html_text(pg_source, date_selector)

    url_selector = "a.WlydOe"
    article_urls = parse_html_urls(pg_source, url_selector)

    print(publish_dates)
    print(article_urls)
```

This is the output I recieved:

```
['Dec 14, 2018', 'Dec 20, 2018', 'Dec 14, 2018', 'Dec 5, 2018', 'Dec 4, 2018', 'Dec 3, 2018', 'Dec 6, 2018', 'Dec 10, 2018', 'Dec 19, 2018', 'Dec 18, 2018']
['https://www.goupstate.com/story/news/2018/12/14/coca-cola-plants-new-owners-mull-possibilites-for-spartanburg-landmark/6643089007/', 'https://www.esmmagazine.com/packaging-design/coca-cola-invests-in-new-technology-for-rpet-production-68822', 'https://www.fooddive.com/news/coca-cola-invests-in-pet-recycling-company/544407/', 'https://resource-recycling.com/plastics/2018/12/05/growing-pet-reclaimer-to-supply-coca-cola-bottlers/', 'https://www.bizjournals.com/atlanta/news/2018/12/04/coca-colas-new-aim-becoming-most-optimistic-brand.html', 'https://www.packaging-gateway.com/news/loop-cepg-pet-plastic/', 'https://www.businesswire.com/news/home/20181206005571/en/James-Quincey-to-Succeed-Muhtar-Kent-as-Chairman-of-The-Coca-Cola-Company', 'https://www.bizjournals.com/atlanta/news/2018/12/10/coca-cola-to-sell-historic-midtown-manhattan.html', 'https://seekingalpha.com/article/4229186-coca-cola-great-blue-chip', 'https://www.mysanantonio.com/food/article/Things-to-know-about-Mexican-Coca-Cola-13471815.php']
```

Comment: Hey, thank you so much, that worked for me! I am not sure though how to move on to the next page to scrape data from all Google news pages, what would I have to do for that?

Comment: Ok nvm, I figured it out lol. Thank you for helping me solve this question :))